# Pubnub Node.js Firewall

Tags: node.js, firewall, pubnub

has anyone tried Pubnub in Node.js behind a corporate firewall..I can get a simple node.js app w/ pubnub working at home but at work I don't receive any messages.  So I assume my firewall is blocking anything except port 80 and 443 internet traffic.

Does that mean when I run node.js with pubnub its using websockets?

Thanks!

```
var pubnub = require("pubnub").init({
    publish_key   : "demo",
    subscribe_key : "demo",
    uuid: 'my_custom_uuid'
});


pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: "my_channel",
     presence: function(m){console.log(m)},
     callback: function(m){console.log(m)}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

## PubNub Works In Corporate Firewalls and Networks

> Full Details: https://github.com/dristic/pubnub-secure-edge/blob/master/README.md#pubnub-secure-edge - please click here to see more.
>
> Full example Code: https://github.com/dristic/pubnub-secure-edge

The PubNub Real-time Network Secure Edge takes a HTTP Traffic and routes requests through the PubNub Network. This allows your web site to be **behind a 100% closed firewall** yet still accept and respond to web requests.

Comment: @ryeo there are no known issues with PubNub on Node through home firewalls. But if you experience any difficulties, we're happy to help, just shoot us a line at support@pubnub.com

Comment: @ryeo can you mark this question as **"Answered"** or let us know if you need more details.